# Having problem with this pointer returning function

Tags: c

I'm having some problems with a simple function call I'm trying to write; basically, the function takes a `string` and a `character` argument and returns a `pointer` to the `first instance` of that character in the string. The call in this instance uses a for loop to use pointers to strings to print out 4 strings. I've tried fiddling around with a bunch of things but can't get the function and call to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define NUMBER 4

char * strsrch(char * string, char x);
int main(void)
{
    char * ptr[NUMBER];
    int x;
    char * word[NUMBER] = {"This is string 1", "Now string 2", "Proceeding through string 3", "And then, the last string"};
    for(x = 0; x < NUMBER; x++)
        puts(word[x]);
    for(x = 0; x < NUMBER; x++)
        puts(strsrch(word[x], 'i'));


    return 0;
}

char * strsrch(char * string, char x)
{
    while (*string && (*string != x))
        string++;

    if (*string = x)
        return string;
    else
        return NULL;

}
```

Comment: Would abort during the .exe. Fixed now though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This `if (*string = x)` should be `if (*string == x)`

You assigned `x` to `*string` instead of comparing them .

Comment: FUUUUUUUUUUU not again!! Thanks!

Comment: @Matt - the speed of answer indicates the number of time I did it :)

Comment: @Matt: You really should turn up the warning level on your compiler, since all modern compilers will warn about that exact problem if you enable it.

Comment: @Greg Hewgill: Is there a good read on enabling compiler warnings?

Comment: @Greg Hewgill: That's a good idea, will probably save me a lot of time, thanks!

Comment: Aren't compiler warnings only shown on the first build or after a clean? Pretty stupid IMO.

Comment: @James - they are shown when the source is compiled. If there was no change in this file or its dependencies it will not compile again, if it will, the compiler will show the warnings.

Answer (score 3):

It should be:

```
if (*string == x)
```

Answer (score 2):

You have done `if (*string = x)` which will assign the character (value) of `x` into the location pointed by `string` , and if `x` is not `0` then this `if` will be always true. You wanted to compare the value of `x` and the first character of `string` which is done by `if (*string == x)` . This will compare the values.

To avoid such mistakes/typos, in such cases you can define the `char *` as constant to forbid accidental modification of the values which you do not want to be changed. For example in this case you can define your function like:

`char * strsrch(const char * string, char x);`

This will stop you from assigning the value of `x` into the string at the time of compilation.

Also you can use more warning level with your compiler. For example with `gcc` turning on `-Wall` will warn you about the *assignment* .